# Nop-Commerce MarketPlace Azure first Deployment Issue

Tags: azure, nopcommerce, azure-deployment

I'm trying to use install nop-commerce from the marketplace azure.
I create the web app and setting up the sql server in the same wizard.

I'm putting both in the same resource-group name.

However, I'm getting the deploment issue below:

Deployment to resource group 'felisbabies' failed.
Additional details from the underlying API that might be helpful: At least one resource deployment operation failed. Please list deployment operations for details. Please see https://aka.ms/DeployOperations for usage details.

Anyone face this similar sceneario?

Answer (score 0):

You can see here i wrote cosmetic article on it [nopCommerce deployment with azure](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/getting-started-with-azure-vm-azure-sql-database-and-nopcommerce-4-20-installat2/)